# ISC-DHCP-SERVER Warnings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, isc-dhcpd

I have a ubuntu server 18.04 configured with two bonded gigabit ethernet NICs. Upon restarting the DHCP server I noticed the following error/warning. The server starts fine and the bonded link is up, but I think something still may be misconfigured.

As I say everything works but errors and warnings still should not be ignored.

What is wrong with this setup?

```
# systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-11-17 20:08:13 GMT; 1min 15s ago
        Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
Main PID: 220139 (dhcpd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 9332)
    Memory: 6.1M
    CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
         └─220139 dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: 
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: 
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: No subnet declaration for enp2s0f0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: ** Ignoring requests on enp2s0f0.  If this is not what
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]:    to which interface enp2s0f0 is attached. **
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: 
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
Nov 17 20:08:13 hostname.com dhcpd[220139]: Server starting service.
```

My dhcp configuration is below;

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf
# DHCP declaration including PXE boot filename and option for tftp server ip.

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.254;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 604800;
    next-server 192.168.0.2;
    filename "/lpxelinux.0";
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.2;

#static address reservations (192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.10)

    host NETGEAR_VDSL_DM200_GATEWAY {
        hardware ethernet 8c:3b:ad:c8:20:fe;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.1;
    }

    host UBUNTU_SERVER {
        hardware ethernet c8:cb:b8:c7:c7:50;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.2;
    }

    host NETGEAR_EX7000_ACCESS_POINT {
        hardware ethernet a0:63:91:e9:c8:f0;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.3;
    }
}
```

See my netplan config filebelow;

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/netplan.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: 
    enp2s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  enp2s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0f0, enp2s0f1]
      addresses: [192.168.0.2/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1  
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1,79.79.79.79,79.79.79.80]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: slow
        mii-monitor-interval: 1000
```

If I look at the status on my bonded link, everything looks ok;

```
$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 1000
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable

Slave Interface: enp2s0f1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:26:55:e3:bb:e3
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

Slave Interface: enp2s0f0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:26:55:e3:bb:e2
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

$ ethtool bond0
Settings for bond0:
Supported ports: [ ]
Supported link modes:   Not reported
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: No
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 2000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Other
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
Link detected: yes
```

Comment: i think your dhcpd service is starting a littlebit too fast when the bond between your card is not fully active, perhaps a second of delay before the start of the dhcpd service would do the trick !

Comment: But this happens even when just restarting the DHCP server.

Comment: check `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` and see if there is a bind on interface enp2s0f0 under `INTERFACES=`